# Interior, closure and frontier of sets

Tags: general-topology

I've tried to find the interior, closure and frontier of the following subsets of $\mathbb{IR}^2$:

1) A=$\{(x,y)| 1<x^2+y^2 \leq2\}$

2) B=$\ {\mathbb{IR}^2\setminus{K}}$ such that $K=\{(x,y)| x= 0\ $v$       y=0\}$

3) C=${\mathbb{IR}^2\setminus{K}}$ such that $K=\{(x,sin(\frac{1}{x}))| x > 0\}$

While I was able to solve 1) and 2), I have trouble with 3). My idea is that the interior of 3) is given by $C\setminus{L}$
such that L=$\{(0,y) | y \in [-1,1] \}$.

My idea was to show first that for each point p in L there is a sequence of elements in K with p as its limit. This would imply that each neighborhood of p contains elements from K, so p cannot be a point in the interior.

This works for p=(0,0) but I find it difficult to construct the sequence in cases where y is not zero. Is it possible to do this in an easy way or is there another, easier way?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{IR}^2$?

Comment: It denotes the two-dimensional euclidean plane with the usual topology.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=(0,y)\in L$. Since $y\in [-1,1]$, there exists a number $t>0$ such that $y=\sin t$. Then $\sin (t+2\pi n)= \sin t=y$ for each natural $n$, thus a sequence $\{(\frac 1{t+2\pi n},\sin (t+2\pi n))\}$ belongs to $K$ and converges to $p$.